# Which is a faster USB protocol RS232 or PS/2

Tags: usb, protocols

A manufacture just asked me

**For the USB interface , we have two communication protocols , one is USB to RS232 ,  one is USB to PS/2 .**

Which one is faster? This is a USB Devise.

Answer (score 2):

Originally, RS232 maxed out at 20kbps, but now it is 1.5 Mbps. PS/2 did not have a rate. It transmits serial data as 10-16 kHz, which means it probably tops out at about 20kbps.

RS232 is better (you do not need to reboot for it to be recognized) and faster.

http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/SemtechCorp/mXryxtw.pdf